# Is onActivityResult() method called after a config change?

Tags: android, onactivityresult, android-configchanges

Activity A starts for result activity B. The user rotate the smartphone. The user press the back button. Activity B is finished. Activity A is re-created. After the `onCreate()` method, is the `onActivityResult()` method of activity A called?

Comment: *After the onCreate() method, is the onActivityResult() method of activity A called?* yes, what is the real problem?(besides you will get fresh new activity instance)

Comment: Can you give me a reference about this or explain why you say that?

Comment: It is stated in startActivityForResult()  documentation (of course you can tell OS that you don't want to recreate activity  on config change) Again, what is the real problem?